# disable links on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have an app were you can create elements, i.e. Text-element and append it to a div

And then you can also add a link to that element.

But I can't get to disable the link within the div (not removing the attr. but just disable it)

I looking for something like this:

```
    $('#container a').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

To disable all links within the div.Container? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use delegated events with the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, which is designed to handle the exact situation you're describing:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: +1 - This is more appropriate since your links are *dynamically* injected. But the e argument is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you have is right except for the missing argument `e` - or just `return false` and forget about `e`.

```
// note the argument 'e'
$('#container a').click(function() {
    return false; // preventDefault + stopPropagation
});
```

Comment: you don't need the param unless you're going to use it.

Comment: @KevinB - Totally. Changed to `return false`, and forgot to change the desc. Answer edited.